# Imageview shrinks on edge of my screen

Tags: android, imageview

If I want to move my imageview's position to where a portion of the right side of the image will be extending past the visible screen the image tends to shrink and all of the image tends to stay within the edge of the screen, the same can be said if I lower the image to extend past the bottom of the screen, the image shrinks and never extends past the lower edge of the screen,

yet if I move the image's position up or the the left the image size is not shrunken and the image extends past the screen like I want it to, I'm curious if anyone has any advice to how I can fix this problem thankyou

```
    mainLayout = (ViewGroup)findViewById(R.id.id_layout);

    deviceScreenSize = new Point();

    thisContext = this;

    mainDisplay = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
    mainDisplay.getSize(deviceScreenSize);
    offsetX = (deviceScreenSize.x / 320.0f);
    offsetY = (deviceScreenSize.y / 568.0f);

    mainIMG = new ImageView(this);
    mainIMG.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.myimg));
    SetPos(0, 0, 320, 568);
    mainIMG.setLayoutParams(layoutPositioner);
    mainLayout.addView(mainIMG);

    setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);

}

public void SetPos(float x, float y, float width, float height) {
    layoutPositioner = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
    layoutPositioner.topMargin = (int)(y * offsetY);
    layoutPositioner.leftMargin = (int)(x * offsetX);
    layoutPositioner.width = (int)(width * offsetX);
    layoutPositioner.height = (int)(height * offsetY);
}

public void SetPosWithoutOffset(float x, float y, float width, float height) {
    layoutPositioner = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
    layoutPositioner.topMargin = (int)(y);
    layoutPositioner.leftMargin = (int)(x);
    layoutPositioner.width = (int)(width);
    layoutPositioner.height = (int)(height);
}
```

Here's a visual example of the problem
[image: descrip]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That happens because you handle only **left** and **top** margins when positioning in the method `SetPos()`:

```
layoutPositioner.topMargin = (int)(y * offsetY);
layoutPositioner.leftMargin = (int)(x * offsetX);
```

So, to solve such issue you have to handle all the directions the following way:

```
// first get screen width and height 
DisplayMetrics metrices = new DisplayMetrics();
this.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrices);
int windowWidth = metrices.widthPixels;
int windowHeight = metrices.heightPixels;

//then set your margins 
int x_cord = (int)(x * offsetX);
int y_cord = (int)(y * offsetY);
layoutPositioner.topMargin = y_cord;
layoutPositioner.leftMargin = x_cord;
layoutPositioner.bottomMargin = windowHeight - (y_cord - your_image.getHeight());
layoutPositioner.rightMargin= windowWidth - (x_cord - your_image.getWidth());
```